# Fast and flexible PDF generator on *NIX system

Tags: php, pdf, pdf-generation

We are building a LAMP application that also needs to generate loads of complex PDF reports.
I'm looking for a library that runs on our Debian server and allows us to generate these reports.

The language isn't of great importance (java, python, php, perl, ...) as long as it's stable, flexible and supports Unicode. LTR and RTL writing systems are mandatory and if chinese is also supported it would be totally awsome.

I've already found ReportLab which looks promising, any other suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[JasperReports](http://jasperforge.org/projects/jasperreports) is a good bet for generating reports using Java.